# request api on localhost from local openwhisk action

Tags: javascript, networking, openwhisk

I've setup a local instance of openwhisk running on docker using [openwhisk-devtools](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-devtools). I've created an action that attempts to hit an API on my machine running at port 8081. The code is something likes this:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

async function main () {

  let response = null;

  try {
    response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8081/api/health-check');
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      payload: {
        error: error
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    payload: {
      headers: response.headers
    }
  };
}

global.main = main;
```

The error I get is:

```json
{
  "code": "ECONNREFUSED",
  "config": {
      "headers": {
          "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
          "User-Agent": "axios/0.20.0"
      },
      "maxBodyLength": -1,
      "maxContentLength": -1,
      "method": "get",
      "timeout": 0,
      "transformRequest": [
          null
      ],
      "transformResponse": [
          null
      ],
      "url": "http://localhost:8081/api/health-check",
      "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
      "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
  },
  "message": "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8081",
  "name": "Error",
  "stack": "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8081\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)"
}
```

I assume this is because localhost points to whatever docker container is running the action. How can I get this request to go to my dev machine?

Comment: This article should be able to help you access the host from your docker container: https://dev.to/bufferings/access-host-from-a-docker-container-4099

Comment: I read that article, `host.docker.internal` resolves to `127.0.0.1:80`. So I tried just requesting `127.0.0.1:8081` which resulted in ECONNREFUSED. In terms of enabling docker `host` networking mode, I've taken a look at the `openwhisk-devtools/docker-compose/docker-compose.yml` and i'm not sure what service configuration to modify.

Answer (score 1):

After printing the value of `process.env` I found a property:

```json
"__OW_API_HOST": "https://192.168.2.61",
```

At first I wasn't really sure what it was, but I tried out a request here and it worked:

```js
axios.get('http://192.169.2.61:8081/api/health-check')
```

So maybe `process.env.__OW_API_HOST` contains an ip pointing to your local machine you can use.